# '<methodname>' has multiple definitions with identical signatures error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, subsonic

I have been trying to use Subsonic 3 in a test application in order to understand how it works.  However, when it builds the vb files from the database the files are full of *'' has multiple definitions with identical signatures* errors.  I am using Visual Studio 2008 configured for VB.

Has anyone else seen this problem and have suggestions for resolving it.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Can you profile examples of the the method names? Currently, my only thoughts relate to the fact that vb is case insensive whereas other languages are not. For example: Foo() and foo() are legit in c# but are not in vb.